# How to add Arrays into Numpy stack Dynamically in Python

Tags: python, numpy

here is my numpy arrays

I have to add them dynamically

means, x is coming from Loop and i want to add them like the `np.stack` , i attached the code below

```
x=np.array(([1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]))
b=x
z=np.stack((x, b))
z
#output
 array([[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]], 
      [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]])
```

if attached b again into `z` using  `np.stack((x, b))` , it gives me an error

`ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`

can anyone tell me how to do that??

Comment: one solution would be to create a list and append them. z = [], z.append(x) on every iteration (every iteration you get a new x right?) and in the end just convert it back z = np.asarray(z) and you have an array. Would it work or you need numpy array all the time?

Comment: right every iteration i get x as a numpy array! @elgordorafiki , let me try this

Comment: Using any of the `concatenate` or `?stack` in a loop is a bad idea (inefficient).  But with `stack` there's the added complication that it adds a dimension each time.  It clearly isn't designed for iterative use.

Answer (score 0):

In `numpy`, there are many ways to stack arrays; your initial array has a shape of `(5,2)` and looks like this:

```
[[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

which you could stack **horizontally** using `np.hstack(x,b)` to get:

```
[[1 2 1 2]
 [1 2 1 2]
 [1 2 1 2]
 [1 2 1 2]
 [1 2 1 2]] # shape: (5, 4), i.e. five arrays of shape 4
```

or stack **vertically** using `np.vstack(x,b)` to get

```
[[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]] # shape: (10, 2), i.e. 10 arrays of shape 2
```

or stack into the **depth** using `np.dstack(x,b)` to get:

```
[[[1 1]
  [2 2]]

 [[1 1]
  [2 2]]

 [[1 1]
  [2 2]]

 [[1 1]
  [2 2]]

 [[1 1]
  [2 2]]] # shape: (5, 2, 2), i.e. five arrays of shape (2,2)
```

When you use `np.stack()` however, numpy will create a **new axis** to join the arrays like:

```
[[[1 2]
  [1 2]
  [1 2]
  [1 2]
  [1 2]]

 [[1 2]             the new axis!
  [1 2]             |  i.e. two arrays of shape (5,2)
  [1 2]             |
  [1 2]             v
  [1 2]]] # shape: (2, 5, 2)
```

This, now, is the solution to your problem: you're trying to "append" arrays in a loop, but `np.stack()` will try to *add a new dimension every step*, which will not work as expected. Depending on the shape you want to achieve, you should use one of the other methods, I suppose.